# How does foreach work?

Tags: php, foreach, php-internals

I have an issue which I can't explain for now. It's well-known that `foreach` in PHP works with *copy* of array, i.e. it copies the array first and then iterates through it. All fine and dandy. But this is weird:

```
$array = ['foo' => 1];
foreach($array as $k => & $v)
{
   $array['bar'] = 2;
   echo $v;
}
```

This will result in `1`. Next, if we add another element to the array (just to be sure, we'll run this code in separate file so it doesn't affect the `refcount` or anything else for these test cases):

```
$array = ['foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2];
foreach($array as $k => & $v)
{
   $array['baz'] = 3;
   echo $v;
}
```

Bingo! We have `1`, `2` and `3` printed. Why? If PHP works on the array by reference, then it should result in `1` and `2` for the first case. And if PHP works with a copy, then it should result in `1` and `2` (without `3`) for the second case.

My question is a continuation for [this great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works). Yes, I'm aware about how  copying works. But we have same `refcount` for both cases. Why the results are different, is currently beyond my understanding.